# Prove that $a_n$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

> 1. Let $\,\,\,\left(a_{n}\right)_{\ n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}\,\,\,}$ be the sequence of integers defined recursively by
>      $$
>    a_{1} = a_{2} = 1\,,\qquad\quad a_{n + 2} = 7a_{n + 1} -a_{n} - 2\quad
>    \mbox{for}\quad n \geq 1
>    $$
> 2. Prove that $a_{n}$ is a perfect square for every $n$.

We have $a_{3} = 4, a_{4} = 25, a_{5} = 169,\ldots$

Is there a way we can simplify the recursion or get its closed form in order to get that it is a perfect square ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For first, we may translate our sequence in order to have some sequence fulfilling $b_{n+2}=7b_{n+1}-b_n$. For such a purpose, it is enough to set $a_n=b_{n}+\frac{2}{5}$, leading to $b_0=b_1=\frac{3}{5}$. Now the characteristic polynomial of the sequence $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is
$$ p(x)=x^2-7x+1 $$
with roots given by $\frac{7\pm 3\sqrt{5}}{2}$, so the explicit form of $b_n$ is given by:
$$ b_n = A\left(\frac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2+B\left(\frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n $$
where the values of the constants $A,B$ are fixed by $b_0$ and $b_1$:
$$ b_n = \frac{-\sqrt{5}+3}{10}\left(\frac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2+\frac{\sqrt{5}+3}{10}\left(\frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n. $$
Now the identity:
$$\boxed{ a_n = b_n+\frac{2}{5} = F_{2n-1}^2 }$$
is a simple consequence of the closed formula for Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Can you explain the last equality?

Comment: @user19405892: what is to explain? Plug in the explicit formula for Fibonacci numbers and check that equality holds.

Comment: I don't see how it is obvious that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2n-1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2n-1}\right) = \frac{-\sqrt{5}+3}{10}\left(\frac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\frac{\sqrt{5}+3}{10}\left(\frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\dfrac{2}{5}.$$

Comment: @user19405892: it would be worthwhile to compute the fourth power of $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$ before checking that. After that, it is really trivial.

Comment: I still don't see how to do it and how taking the fourth power relates.

Comment: @user19405892: can't you see how  $$ F_{2n-1}^2=\left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left( \varphi^{2n-1}+\bar{\varphi}^{2n-1} \right) \right]^2 $$ relates to $(\varphi^4)^n$?

Comment: @user19405892: no, since the square of $x^{2n-1}$ is $x^{4n-2}$.

Comment: Then it is $\dfrac{1}{5}(\phi^{4n-2}+\bar{\phi}^{4n-2}+2)$. I still don't see what to do.

Comment: @user19405892: all right, now compute $\frac{1}{\phi^2}$, $\phi^4$ and write $\phi^{4n-2}$ as $(\phi^4)^n\cdot\frac{1}{\phi^2}$. Got it?

Answer (score 9):

Define the sequence given by $b_1=1,b_2=1$ and $b_{n+2}=3b_{n+1}-b_{n}$ for $n>0$.

To prove that $a_n=b_n^2$ we just have to show:

$b_{n+2}^2=7b_{n+1}^2-b_{n}^2-2$.

Of course $b_{n+2}^2=9b_{n+1}^2-6b_{n+1}b_n+b_{n-1}^2$

So to finish we just need to prove $3b_{n+1}b_n=b_{n+1}^2+b_n^2+1$.

Notice $b_{n+1}^2+b_n^2+1=b_{n+1}(3b_n-b_{n-1})+b_n^2+1=3b_{n+1}b_n-b_{n+1}b_{n-1}+b_n^2+1$.

So to finish we just have to show $b_{n+1}b_{n-1}-b_n^2=1$

To do this we notice that

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^n
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{n+3} & b_{n+2}\\
b_{n+2} & b_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore the the determinant of the matrix on the right is always $1$, and that determinant is $b_{n+3}b_{n+1}-b_{n+2}^2$

Comment: Is it worth mentioning how you came up with the $b_n$ recurrence? I found it by noting its role in defining the odd-indexed entries in the Fibonacci sequence, which, when squared, seemed to match up with the OP's sequence ... not sure if you found it by other means.

Comment: I wrote out the square roots of each term and I looked for a linear recursion that satisfied them.

Answer (score 6):

**Cleaned Up for Clarity:**

Recall the Fibonacci sequence:

$$1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, \ldots$$

You have here the sequence:

$$1^2, 2^2, 5^2, 13^2, \ldots$$

**So:** It looks to be the odd entries of the Fibonacci sequence, squared.

To check if this holds, we proceed as follows:

Note $F(2k-1)^2$ and $a(k)$ have the same first two values; so we can verify whether they produce the same sequences by checking if $F(2k-1)^2$ satisfies the same recurrence relation as $a(k)$.

*Short Answer:* The relation holds for $F(2k-1)^2$ as can be shown by appealing directly to the closed formula for the Fibonacci entries. **QED**.

---

*Longer Answer:* To check that the relation holds, we first recall the recursive $a(k)$ definition:

$$a(k+2) = 7a(k+1) - a(k) - 2$$

To prove that $F(2k-1)^2$ satisfies this relation, we check if the following holds:

$$F(\text{the }k+2\text{nd odd})^2 = 7F(\text{the }k+1\text{st odd})^2 - F(\text{the }k\text{th odd})^2 - 2$$

**Note:** The $(k+2)$nd odd is $2k+3$; the $(k+1)$st odd is $2k+1$; the $k$th odd is $2k-1$.

Since we have an explicit formula for the $n$th entry in the Fibonacci sequence, we can use it to check whether the recurrence relation above holds. To check that it holds, it suffices to subtract the LHS from the RHS and see if it returns $0$; this is done in the Wolfram Alpha link [**here**](http://tinyurl.com/fibodd).

The result is given as $-4 \sin^2 (\pi n)$, which is not the cleanest method of verification; but observe that any natural multiple of $\pi$ is zero when evaluated at $\sin$. So the result follows. **QED**.

Comment: The Fibonacci numbers don't follow that recurrence.

Comment: @WillFisher The *odd* Fibonacci numbers, which I have denoted $f(n)$; note that I also have the Fibonacci numbers denoted using a capital $F$.

Comment: This seems to be a very good idea. +1

Comment: The actual sequence is http://oeis.org/A001519.

Comment: Can we solve the recurrence in the question?

Comment: As @kennytm points out, we can find the sequence for the square roots, although I am not able to show that they match.

Comment: I think we may have to do something with thedeterminant of the recursion's matrix.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling If we let $a_n = b_n+\dfrac{2}{5}$, then $b_{n+2}=7 b_{n+1}-b_{n}$.

Comment: @kennytm That is *not* the sequence but the square roots of the elements of the sequence...

Comment: We can use the recurrence  $a(n) = 3*a(n-1) - a(n-2)$  and prove that $a(n)^2$ satisfies the above recurrence

Comment: Expressing $F(m+4)$ and $F(m+2)$ in terms of $F(m)$ and  $F(m+1)$, we get $F(m+4)^2 - 7 F(m+2)^2 + F(m)^2 = -2 F_m^2-2 F_m F_{m+1}+2 F_{m+1}^2$, and this is $2 (-1)^m$ by a well-known identity.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see how the strong induction works.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling We establish $a(1)$ and $a(2)$ are $F(1)^2$ and $F(3)^2$, respectively. Given this as a starting point, does the recurrence relation hold? i.e., Is it true that $7a(n+1) - a(n) - 2$ yields the next odd-indexed entry of the Fibonacci sequence, squared? To show this, I used the inductive hypothesis to re-write $a(k)$ as $F(2k-1)^2$; then I wrote out the given relation, with the left hand side subtracted from the right hand side, to see whether it would yield $0$, hence equality. And it did.

Comment: Really, I wouldn't have thought it would immediately yield equality.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I have no idea how your claimed induction works based on what little is written in your answer. Does it involve some exotic Fibonacci identity, or is it simple algebra? There are many possible ways to do these things, so it is not easy to uniquely infer which one you intend. Proofs should not leave such large doubts in the mind of the reader.

Comment: @BillDubuque Okay! I have edited in a more detailed description. Does this seem clearer now? (The answer is/was: simple algebra and the explicit formula for the $n$th entry in the Fibonacci sequence.)

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Thanks for clarifying. I didn't realize that the method you intended was the same as the brute-force Alpha computation by using the closed form. I was misled by your remark  that the method was inductive. But it seems what you meant was simply to deduce that $\,a_n = F_{2n-1}^2$ by applying the *uniqueness* theorem for recurrences (no need to repeat its trivial inductive proof in this special case).

Answer (score 4):

**A brute-force approach**

$$b_{n} = 3b_{n-1} - b_{n-2}$$
Squaring on both sides,
$$b_n^2 = 9b_{n-1}^2+b_{n-2}^2 -6b_{n-1}b_{n-2} $$
Similarly,
$$b_{n-1}^2 = 9b_{n-2}^2+b_{n-3}^2 -6b_{n-2}b_{n-3} $$
Subtracting,
$$b_n^2 - b_{n-1}^2 = 9b_{n-1}^2 - 8b_{n-2}^2 - b_{n-3}^2 -6a_{n-2}(b_{n-1}-b_{n-1}) $$

Since,
$$3b_{n-2} = b_{n-1} + b_{n-3}$$

$$b_n^2 - b_{n-1}^2 = 9b_{n-1}^2 - 8b_{n-2}^2 - b_{n-3}^2 -2(b_{n-1} + b_{n-3})(b_{n-1}-b_{n-3}) $$

$$b_n^2 - b_{n-1}^2 = 9b_{n-1}^2 - 8b_{n-2}^2 - b_{n-3}^2 -2(b_{n-1}^2 - b_{n-3}^2) $$

$$b_n^2 = 8(b_{n-1}^2 - b_{n-2}^2) + b_{n-3}^2 $$

Summing up both sides from 3 to n,
$$\sum_{i=3}^{n}(b_i^2-b_{i-3}^2)=8\sum_{i=3}^{n}(b_{i-1}^2 - b_{i-2}^2)$$
$$\sum_{i=3}^{n}b_i^2-\sum_{j=0}^{n-3}b_{j}^2=8(\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}b_{k}^2 - \sum_{l=1}^{n-2}b_{l}^2)$$
$$b_n^2 + b_{n-1}^2 +b_{n-2}^2 - b_{2}^2 -b_{1}^2-b_{0}^2= 8(b_{n-1}^2 - b_1^2) $$
$$b_n^2 = 7b_{n-1}^2 - b_{n-2}^2 -2 $$
$\therefore a_n=b_n^2$ satisfies the recurrence.

Hence,proved

Comment: Nice, you deserve a medal for your effort.

Comment: It will probably help many readers if you say more about how you summed up both sides.

Comment: Also, use $b_n$ instead of $a_n$.